# Stored procedure returns null to VB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a problem I just can't figure out, my Google-fu has failed me too, so I signed in just to get some expert help.

The problem is complex, with a few red herrings, for what I can figure out, plus as we deal with sensitive information, I can't give the exact code. Please bear with me, I'll try to be as precise and descriptive as I can.

Short version of the problem: I have a stored procedure (on a SQL Server 2008 R2 server) which returns one row when executed directly on the server. When the same stored procedure is executed via VB.net code (Visual Studio 2013 environment), one of the column's value is changed to DBNull.

Long version with code example:

Here is a cleaned up version of the stored procedure

```
Create PROCEDURE MySP
    @inputParms [five of them]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserCanRun int
    DECLARE @ThisApp INT

    EXEC @UserCanRun = dbname.dbo.CheckUserCanRun @InputParm1, @ThisApp --security check

    IF @UserCanRun = 0 --Means no problem, can continue
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ExtraInfo varchar(100)

        SELECT @ExtraInfo = typeID + ' - ' + typeName
        FROM [three joined tables]
        WHERE [conditions using some @InputParm4]

        SELECT DISTINCT 
            col1, ..., [colN-1], @ExtraInfo as colN, [colN+1], ..., colM
        FROM 
            [8 joined tables and subqueries]
        WHERE 
            [more conditions with @InputParms2 to 5]
    END
END
GO
```

This stored procedure runs just fine when executed directly on the database; it returns one row, with all the (available) info having their value set correctly. (You'll notice colN; it's the one giving me trouble; co-workers assure me the fact it is using value from a variable shouldn't be a problem.)

Now, when I call it from VB.net code:

```
dim rTable As DataTable
dim myCmd = New SqlCommand(SPName, myConnectionString)
dim parameter As SQLParameter
dim rValue As Integer = 0

[set SQL parameters]

If not myCmd is Nothing Then
    If myCmd.Connection.State = connectionstate.Closed Then
        [bit of security check code]
        command.Connection.Open()
    End If
    Dim myAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCmd
    myAdapter.Fill(rTable) 'problem!
    ReturnValue = CInt(myCmd.Parameters(RETURN_VALUE_FIELD).Value)
End If
[more code]
```

If I do a quick watch on the `rTable` after the `myAdapter.Fill` command has executed, the value `rTable.Rows(0).Item([M])` returns DBNull, while it was not `DBNull` when fetched directly in the SP, using exactly the same parameters.

I don't have a data set for that table; you can see it uses a generic `DataTable` (the code is adapted from an application specific object to simplify all stored procedure calls, so I can't create a dataset and use it at this level either). So I don't think.

I have checked for the validity of the value; I have even checked the Unicode value of each character of the `@ExtraInfo` value to make sure there was not some control character that would have been put in accidentally. It matched the value shown, so no bad character messing up the value.

This is used in a few places in the code, but seems to fail for one specific set of data on our production environment; I haven't been able to reproduce the problem on our development environment. So I can't just go in and play with it.

Would anyone know what else could cause a column's value to go from a non-null, non-empty `varchar` to DBNull by going through `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()`? I can't step into that call, so I am blind.

(Also worth of note, maybe: I have been using VB.net for only about two years, debugging existing systems, so I may be missing something obvious; although my more experienced colleagues don't understand it either.)

Edited to add the final word on the problem: I never found the solution, except good old Murphy's Law. After letting this aside for a while, I asked a co-worker to take a look. As I was showing him, the problem didn't occur. Another test later confirmed it was behaving normally. I can't promise anyone Murphy's law is a sure solution, but I can only suggest there was some transient error that disappeared on its own. If it happens to you, good luck, and please let us know if you find a solution, or even a way to diagnose it. Thank you!

Comment: You said you successfully ran the procedure on the server, but was it `CheckUserCanRun` or was it `MySp` that you were able to run?

Comment: Did you forget to specify the CommandType to be a CommandType.StoredProcedure?

Comment: I ran the whole thing, so MySp. The CheckUserCanRun function is a security check to make sure no unauthorized user will see the data.

Comment: Steve: nope, not forgotten in the original code; just skipped (didn't know it was important) in my trimmed down version. Maybe I should specify that the whole calling a stored procedure works just fine in all the other calls, and even the same stored procedure call with other data.

Comment: I can't explain this behavior with the trimmed info that you can submit. The only advice that I feel to give is to, temporarily  reduce the complexity of the stored procedure until your field value reappears and then start to analyze from there.

Comment: just for debugging fun, in the stored procedure set @ExtraInfo to a sentinal value in the stored procedure before you assign using the select statement like 'debug me' and see if you still get a null back in the field when executed.

Comment: Jeremy: I wish. But since it only happens with production data (so in the production environment), I can't play with it. I guess I'll try to reproduce the problem again; I may have missed something. If I get to reproduce it, I'll be more free to play with things.

Comment: Does the SP run on the same account in SSMS and in VB? Also are other values from the `rTable` correct? As a debugging advice, you can create `mySP_copy` and play with it.

Comment: Did you try to put the column value in isnull in your stored procedure? `ex. COLUMN = ISNULL(COLUMN_VALUE, '')`

Comment: You didn't include the part where you add the parameters. Is your parameter created with `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`?

Comment: Alex: technically, yes. It is worth checking, but since the problem arises only in one case (so far), I doubt that would be the source.

Comment: Jelliaes: I can't change the stored procedure for testing purposes since it happens only in one case in production, so no, I didn't. It wouldn't solve the problem anyway, as a value is expected; having an empty value instead of NULL still doesn't give me the value in the database.

Comment: Scott: yes, `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` is set for the return value. Reading the code, the `ParameterDirection.Input` may not be set for all input parameters individually, but if this has been a problem, I expect we'd have had problems much earlier. (The code has been in use for about 15 years.)

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure needs SET NOCOUNT ON at the beginning

Comment: It doesn't. And this is not an answer. No -1 yet.

Comment: You're right. I had it backwards. OLEDB required NOCOUNT unless you were going to handle the multiple recordsets it returned. .Net SQLCommand actually requires the record count to function.

Comment: The problem is unknown from OP and is different from OP reads. I suspect XY problem.